# Probability of an obtuse angle in a scalene triangle

Tags: probability

I tried to discuss this problem few months back but could not explain it well enough: [What is the probability of an angle to be obtuse in a triangle (presumed to be on a plane rather than curved surface)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661081/what-is-the-probability-of-an-angle-to-be-obtuse-in-a-triangle-presumed-to-be-o)

Here's my fully prepped answer:

1. You imagine two equal circles whose circumference passes through the center of the other circle. The radius of these circles is the longest side of the triangle that you want to form.
2. You form a circle with the diameter of the common radius of the bigger circles.
3. You choose a random point in this intersection area of the bigger circles.

When the third point selected is within the smaller circle, we get an obtuse angle opposite to the longest side i.e. the larger radius. That will be the only obtuse angle in the triangle as angles are proportional to the sides opposite to it and there can be a maximum of one obtuse angle in a triangle.

You calculate the exact probability of an obtuse triangle using your method by finding the ratio of the area of the smaller circle to the area of the intersection of the two bigger circles. This ratio is equal to $$\frac{\pi}{8\pi - 4\sqrt{3}}$$ which is approximately 0.11.

This is the probability of in any triangle. In equilateral triangles obtuse angles do not exist. For Isosceles, we shall try another construct.

1. You make a circle and consider the radius to be one of the equal sides.
2. You choose another random radius.

This construct gets an obtuse angle between the two radii as half, and there is 1 in 3 chances that we select the apex angle, giving us the probability in an isosceles triangle to be $$\frac{1}{6}$$

Hence the probability in a scalene triangle is $$\frac{\pi}{8\pi - 4\sqrt{3}} - \frac{1}{6}$$ which is approximately 0.08

I am interested in other methods of finding the answer, or fallacies in my logic.

Comment: Can you draw out this setup and post as pic? I'll admit its hard to follow the three-step construction.